# Python: libc fallocate returns with failure

Tags: python

I am trying to fallocate a tempfile, but unfortunately the following code returns -1 (failure):

```
import ctypes, tempfile
from ctypes import *

t_file=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True, dir=".", prefix="temp_file_")

libc=cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
libc.fallocate(t_file.fileno(), c_int(0), c_longlong(0), c_longlong(102400))
```

However, I can do fine with the following from command line

```
hdparm --fallocate 10 ./temp_file_foo
```

which should do the same. If it matters, this is done on an ext4 filesystem.

A separate question I have is whether libc.fallocate writes zeros to the disk, or does it mark the blocks as uninitialized?

Comment: Obvious request for clarification: What is errno set to when `libc.fallocate` returns? Alternatively, what does an `strace` look like around this call?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about strace. It returns fallocate(4,0,0,0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)

Comment: More clarification, if I change c_longlong to c_int in the last two arguments, fallocate works. It seems it doesn't like c_longlong. However, I need to allocate most of the empty space on large disks, which means c_int won't do. Besides calling fallocate many times, is there a work around? Does hdparm have the same issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're on a 32-bit system, where the `fallocate` system call takes a (32-bit) integer by default. Some systems will also have a 64-bit counterpart in `fallocate64`, which takes a 64-bit offset and length. Try that instead.

Note that native 64-bit systems only have `fallocate`, but it takes 64-bit arguments.

Comment: Thank you! I am on a 32 bit system. Does fallocate64 behave the same way as fallocate, i.e. no data initialization? Unfortunately, my version of libc does not have fallocate64.

Comment: Yes - the only difference between the two functions is the size of the arguments they take.

Comment: Any idea where I could get it from? I'm running on debian testing and the libc in their repositories doesn't seem to have it.