# How to make writing to a file faster in python?

Tags: python

I have a task to create big file with random data. I started doing with the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

N=10
rand_file = open("file_name", 'w');

for i in range(1, 7000000):
  print(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                for x in range(N)),
        file=rand_file)
```

Looking at the write throughput I get on disk with this program I feel this is not the fastest way. I would like to create a 100MB contiguous buffer space, write the strings in the buffer, and then flush it to file every time the buffer fills up. How to do this in python? I looked at io.BufferedWriter, but could not understand how to use it to write into a file.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, what operating system are you using?

Comment: What speed are you getting at the minute?  Are you using an SSD? Try using an in memory file for comparison.

Comment: I am using a local disk. This machine is running on ec2 and I am using the ephemeral storage which is the local disk. I get less than 1MB/sec of throughput. I measured it using iotop.

Comment: The problem is probably the `print` function flushing every line. Try to use `sys.stdout.write` and explicit `flush` calls, or a `BufferedWriter`(as in the answer).

Comment: Did you see my answer , please ?

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, here is an example of using a BufferedWriter for this:

```
import io
import random
import string

N=10
rand_file = io.FileIO("file_name", 'w')
writer = io.BufferedWriter(rand_file,buffer_size=100000000)

for i in range(1, 7000000):
  writer.write(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(N)))

writer.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the file's buffer size. By default, its only 8k and gets flushed a lot.

```
import random
import time
import string

N = 10
count = 0

start = time.time()
with open('/tmp/xyz','wb',100*(2**20)) as f:
    for i in xrange(1,7000000):
        s = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(N))
        count += len(s)
        f.write(s)
delta = time.time() - start
print count/(2**20), 'mb', count/(delta*(2**20)), 'mbs'
```

This helps you get large contiguous writes which is generally a good thing but won't help your performance all that much. Try keeping the random.choice() calculation, but leave out the printing in your code - it will still take a long time. You are CPU bound, not IO bound.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create a big file, then it should be fast to write to it:

```
import random

N = 2**20

f = open('rand.txt', 'wb')
f.seek(N-1)
f.write('\0')
f.seek(0)

for i in xrange(N-1):
    f.write(chr(random.randint(32,127)))

f.close()
```

Comment: How does that help in making writes faster? seek will move the filepointer ahead by 1024 bytes here, which means the first 1024 bytes will be zeroed.

Comment: @mc_87: this will allocate continuous `N` bytes

Comment: No, that doesn't allocate contiguous N bytes, it only creates a whole that's going to be filled later. `fallocate` and friends are the answer for preallocation. You could either run the `fallocate` command or [use the function from libc via ctypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407792/python-libc-fallocate-returns-with-failure).

Answer (score 0):

Importing `ascii_lower` and `choice` instead of `string` and `random` diminishes the execution's times.
It seems that using the `with` statement to open the file is cause of a light increasing of execution's time.

Instead of writing 7000 lines (in my code I took this number instead of 7000000) , the idea of the last code is to group a number of lines in a string where they are linked by `\n` before to print this string in the file.
Doing so, the number of calls to `print()` is lowered.

To obtain the same total number of lines whith a number of grouped lines that isn't a divisor of the total number of lines, it needs to do some tricky computings in the for-loop and the xrange (better undesrtood by seeing the code).

I also choosed a buffer size in order that it is equal to the number of  bits in the string grouping several lines, while being a multiple of 1024.
Each line of the file must contain 10 characters. The grouped lines are linked with `\n` --> it makes 11 characters. The last grouped line doesn't have a `\n` after it but when `print()` will act, it will add such a character `` `\n ``.
So for **n** grouped lines, there are **n** * 11 characters in the grouping string. As a character==8 bits, it makes **n***11*8 = **n***88.   Then to find n it's easy: it must verify **n***88 = buffer_size. We have just to manage to take a buffer_size multiple of  1024 and multiple of 88 at the same time.

#### EDIT

It appears that trying to adjust the buffer's size doesn't provide a benefit, it's even the contary !

```
from __future__ import print_function

from time import clock
from os.path import getsize

N=10
A,B,C,D,E,F = [],[],[],[],[],[]
repet = 20
total_lines = 7000
```

.

```
import random
import string
for i in xrange(repet):
  te = clock()
  rand_file1 = open("file_name1", 'w')
  for i in range(total_lines):
    print(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                  for x in range(N)),
          file=rand_file1)
  rand_file1.close()
  A.append(clock()-te)
```

.

```
import random
import string
for i in xrange(repet):
  te = clock()
  with open("file_name2", 'w') as rand_file2:
    for i in range(total_lines):
      print(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                    for x in range(N)),
            file=rand_file2)
  B.append(clock()-te)
```

.

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase
for i in xrange(repet):
  te = clock()
  rand_file3 = open("file_name3", 'w')
  for i in range(total_lines):
    print(''.join(random.choice(ascii_lowercase)
                  for x in range(N)),
          file=rand_file3)
  rand_file3.close()
  C.append(clock()-te)
```

.

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase
for i in xrange(repet):
  te = clock()
  rand_file4 = open("file_name4", 'w')
  for i in range(total_lines):
    print(''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase)
                  for x in range(N)),
          file=rand_file4)
  rand_file4.close()
  D.append(clock()-te)
```

.

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase
buffer_size = 22528
grouped_lines = buffer_size/(11*8)
for i in xrange(repet):
  te = clock()
  rand_file5 = open("file_name5", 'w') # <== no buffer's size adjusted here
  for i in range(0, total_lines, grouped_lines):
    u = '\n'.join(''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase)
                            for x in range(N))
                  for y in xrange(min(grouped_lines,total_lines-i)))
    print(u,file=rand_file5)
  rand_file5.close()
  E.append(clock()-te)
```

.

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase
buffer_size = 22528
grouped_lines = buffer_size/(11*8)
for i in xrange(repet):
  te = clock()
  rand_file6 = open("file_name6", 'w', buffer_size)
  for i in range(0, total_lines, grouped_lines):
    u = '\n'.join(''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase)
                            for x in range(N))
                  for y in xrange(min(grouped_lines,total_lines-i)))
    print(u,file=rand_file6)
  rand_file6.close()
  F.append(clock()-te)
```

.

```
t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6=map(min,(A,B,C,D,E,F))
print ('1  %s\n'
       '2  %s  %.3f %%\n'
       '3  %s  %.3f %%\n'
       '4  %s  %.3f %%\n'
       '5  %s  %.3f %%\n'
       '6  %s  %.3f %%\n'
       % (t1,
          t2,t2/t1*100,
          t3,t3/t1*100,
          t4,t4/t1*100,
          t5,t5/t1*100,
          t6,t6/t1*100))


for y in xrange(880,100000,88):
  if y%1024==0:
    print('%d %% 88 == %d   %d %% 1024 == %d'
          % (y,y%88,y,y%1024))

print("\nfile_name1",getsize('file_name1'))
for fn in ("file_name2","file_name3",
           "file_name4","file_name5",
           "file_name6"):
  print(fn,getsize(fn))
```

result

```
1  0.492455605391
2  0.503463149646  102.235 %
3  0.475755717556  96.609 %
4  0.449807168229  91.340 %
5  0.319271024669  64.832 %
6  0.334138277351  67.851 %

11264 % 88 == 0   11264 % 1024 == 0
22528 % 88 == 0   22528 % 1024 == 0
33792 % 88 == 0   33792 % 1024 == 0
45056 % 88 == 0   45056 % 1024 == 0
56320 % 88 == 0   56320 % 1024 == 0
67584 % 88 == 0   67584 % 1024 == 0
78848 % 88 == 0   78848 % 1024 == 0
90112 % 88 == 0   90112 % 1024 == 0

file_name1 84000
file_name2 84000
file_name3 84000
file_name4 84000
file_name5 84000
file_name6 84000
```

Answer (score -3):

Python isn't necessarily the easiest or the fastest way to create a large file with random data. The following bash snippet will create a file of the specified length with random data; see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63795/writing-dev-random-to-file) question for source.

```
dd if=/dev/random iflag=fullblock of=$HOME/randomFile bs=1M count=1
```